# Plot bar chart from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have following pandas dataframe that I would like to plot the `NaN` and `high` values as a `bar plot` in matplotlib:

```
df

               Close 1   Close 2   Close 3   Close 4   Close 5   Close 6  
Index                                                               
NaN            0.000348  0.000975  0.001450  0.001923  0.002483  0.002916   
high           0.001416 -0.000215  0.000058  0.000026 -0.000766 -0.000255
```

The labels on the x-axis shall be the column names. How can this be done?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Try this:  `df.T.plot.bar(rot=0)`

Comment: @MaxU, thank you. Wow, I was expecting a lengthier solution such as presented here: http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/barchart_demo.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can plot transposed DF:

```
In [9]: import matplotlib
   ...: matplotlib.style.use('ggplot')
   ...:

In [10]: df.T.plot.bar(rot=0)
Out[10]: <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot at 0xa1ae240>
```

[image]

with vertical labels:

```
In [14]: df.T.plot.bar(width=0.85, alpha=0.6, figsize=(14,12))
Out[14]: <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot at 0xa3499e8>
```

[image]

Comment: perfect. Just one more question: how can the labels be transposed vertically in this setup?

Comment: many thanks. wouldn't have expected it to be that short. I noticed that you get the vertical labels as well when you set rot=90 in the initial answer.